# Python dataframe if conditions are true column value=1, otherwise 0

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to make a new column that is 0 if any one of about 20 conditions are true, and 1 otherwise. My current code is:

```
conditions=[(lastYear_sale['Low_Balance_Flag'==0])&(lastYear_sale.another_Flag==0),(lastYear_sale['Low_Balance_Flag'==1])&(lastYear_sale.another_Flag==1)]
choices=[1,0]
lastYear_sale['eligible']=np.select(conditions,choices,default=0)
```

So here is a simplified version of the dataframe I have, that looks a little like:

```
data = {'ID':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        'Low_Balance_Flag':[1, 0, 1, 0], 'another_Flag':[0,0,1,1]}
dfr = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to add a column called eligible that is 0 if low balance flag or another_flag are 1, but if all other columns are 0 then eligible should be 1. I get an error from my attempt that just says keyError: False but I can't see what the error is, thanks for any suggestions! :)

Edit: so the output I'd be looking for in this case would be:

```
ID    Low_Balance    another_Flag    Eligible 
 a        1               0           0 
 b        0               0           1 
 c        1               1           0 
 d        0               1           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `conditions` is basically what you need. You just need the proper conditions. I assume the conditions you have are 2 condition clauses separated by comma. If you have a data frame `lastYear_sale` which I believe is supposed to be `dfr` then

```
conditions=((lastYear_sale['Low_Balance_Flag']==0)&(lastYear_sale.another_Flag==0))|((lastYear_sale['Low_Balance_Flag']==1)&(lastYear_sale.another_Flag==1))

print((~conditions).astype(int))

0    1
1    0
2    0
3    0
dtype: int64
```

If your conditions are somewhat dynamic and you need to build them within code you can use [pandas.DataFrame.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to evaluate a string expression you have built.

Edit: I still assume `dfr` is the same as `lastYear_sale`. Also, the data in `dfr` does not match the data in the expected output.

```
#Use either of these
conditions = ~((lastYear_sale['Low_Balance_Flag']==1)|(lastYear_sale.another_Flag==1))
conditions = ~lastYear_sale.eval('Low_Balance_Flag==1|another_Flag==1')

 dfr['eligible'] = conditions.astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks MYousefi! This code throws the same error unfortunately, I don't think conditions in this form works as input for the np.select method?

Comment: Why are you using `np.select` here? The code block you have has some errors in it and I just made some assumptions on how to fix them. I will fix the code to match the description.

Comment: btw the condition you have described `0 if low balance flag or another_flag are 1, but if all other columns are 0 then eligible should be 1` is just a negated `or` statement. The only confusing part is `all other columns`.

Comment: thank you, discrepancy in the table also fixed!